# how to send array of objects to server side in single request in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

i am working in extjs4 MVC and I have been getting stuck at a point which is how to send object array in a single request.
I know how to send single object to server.

1)Here is my some controller code :-

```
    check:function () {
    console.log("Inside check function.");
    //creating objects in javascript
    var obj = new Object();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName(i);
        var radio = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
            if (inputs[j].checked) {
                name = inputs[j].name;
                value = inputs[j].value;
                //obj[i].name1=name;
                obj[i] = {'questionId': name, 'option': value};
                console.log("questionId=" + name + " value=" + value);
                console.log("object name=" + obj[i].questionId + " Object value=" + obj[i].option);

                var check = Ext.ModelManager.create(
                    {
                        questionId: name,
                        option: value,
                    }, 'Balaee.model.qb.QbquestionoptionModel');
                console.log("User Infooooooooo:" + check.get('option'));
            }// End of if statment
        }// End of inner for loop
    }//End of outer for loop
    var storeObject = this.getStore('qb.QbquestionoptionStore');
    storeObject.sync();
    console.log("data send");

}// End of check function
```

2)Model class :---

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.qb.QbquestionoptionModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idproperty:'',//fields property first position pk. 
    fields: ['optionId','questionId','isAnswer','option','media','keyword','mediaTypeId',],
    /*associations:[
    {type:'BelongsTo',  model:'Mediatype',  foreignKey:'mediaTypeId'},
    {type:'BelongsTo',  model:'Qbquestion', foreignKey:'questionId'},
    {type:'HasMany',    model:'Qbregistereduserfreequestionawnser', foreignKey:'answerOptionId'},
    ]*/
});
```

3)Here is my store :---

```
Ext.define('Balaee.store.qb.QbquestionoptionStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Balaee.model.qb.QbquestionoptionModel',
    //autoLoad: true,
    proxy:
    {
        type:'ajax',
        api:
        {
            read:'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=QuestionBank/qbpaper/SetUserAnswer11',
            create: 'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=QuestionBank/qbpaper/SetUserAnswer12',
            update: 'http://localhost/balaee/Balaee/index.php?r=QuestionBank/qbpaper/SetUserAnswer13',
            //destroy: ,
        },//End of api 
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            //root: ,
            //successProperty: ,
        },//End of reader
        writer:
        {
            type:'json',
            root:'data'
        }   
    }//End of proxy
});//End of store
```

how can I solve this? please give some suggestion....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first you have to send it as JSON (at least I recommend that) and that can easily be done cause the **[`Ext.Ajax.request()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request)** method supports this out of the box

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'YourURL',
    jsonData: YourObjectRef, // can be any object or JSON string
    success: function(response, opts) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

And if you want to do it with a store use the type `auto` for the Modelfield. This type can contain any object. Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/xVAem/)** with a list of objects within a model.

Here is a modification of your store configuration. Note that you can either define a `read` only *API* or a *CRUD API*. For the later it is not possible to leave f.e. the `destroy` action unset. You also need to know that a root property within the `writer` implies that you want to *encode* your data, meaning all get send via `get` which is defiantly not what you want.

*Now to what this proxy does:* Per default `batch` will be `true` which would cause the *store* to submit **all** changes at once when sync get called. If there are more then one changes for a action the proxy will submit a array of objects instead of a single one. Now if you don't take care about this you would now need to predict if you get a object or a array of objects for each request. We don't want end up in something like this. But there is the `allowSingle` property on the writer which get us around this. If you set it to `true` it will always send a array of objects back to the server even if there is only one. You now know that you get a array each time.

```
proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    api: {
        read:'index.php?r=...',
        create: 'index.php?r=...',
        update: 'index.php?r=...',
        destroy: 'index.php?r=...',
    },
    reader: {
        type:'json',
        root:'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type:'json',
        allowSingle: false
    }   
}
```

Comment: it works with ajax request. But I want I am using MVC and i want to use store to send data. sorry but can u give me more inofrmation on store to solve this problem.

Comment: @PravinMane As I told you, simply set the type of the Model-field which contains your array (or any other object) to `auto` which will allow you to send none-primitive types in your request. And in case that you just struggle cause you send at one time one model back to server and the other time two so that your deserializer fails then you should set your writer property to `allowSingle: false` as already mentioned. This will force the writer to always send array and any write operation. Not matter if it will contains one or more lements. I hope this answers your question?

Comment: Thanx for reply. Actully i had implemented function to send single record via proxy. But i am not getting how to send multiplerecords. i had created object to store this multiple records. But want to send this multiple value object. So can you please explain how to set that auto to modelfield so that i can send this multiple records. Actually i am very new to extjs so dnt knw how to set that auto. Please help me....

Comment: lot of thanks for reply.finally i solved my problem and thanks to clear my concept.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to submit several records from a store through in a single proxy request as an array, you should configure your writer with the **allowSingle** config to **false**. This will force your proxy request to wrap the request object in an array, even if only a single modle instance is being saved/added/etc.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-allowSingle

```
writer: {
    type:'json',
    root:'data',
    allowSingle: false
}
```